# How are inter-library dependencies resolved in linux?

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I am building a shared library that depends on another shared library.  Specifically I'm building an ALSA plug in that uses symbols from libasound.

I am able to build my shared library by:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname -Wl,libasound_module_pcm_mod.so -lasound  -fPIC  adt_dsp_alsa.o -o libasound_module_pcm_mod.so
```

However when I try to open the library in an application is says it cannot be opened. Running `ldd -d -r libasound_module_pcm_mod.so`  I get lots of undefined references to libasound symbols.

```
ldd -d -r bin/x86/libasound_module_pcm_adt_dsp.so 
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00336000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00167000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x005d4000)
undefined symbol: snd_lib_error (bin/x86/libasound_module_pcm_adt_dsp.so)
```

These symbols are defined in asoundlib

Do I need to build my library differently, or configure my system differently for this to work? I am new to shared libraries so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your `-lasound` is in the wrong place. Most distros run the linker with the `--as-needed` flag, so if you link to a shared library that isn't needed so far on the command line, it'll get omitted.

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname -Wl,libasound_module_pcm_mod.so   -fPIC  adt_dsp_alsa.o -o libasound_module_pcm_mod.so -lasound